# mPDF hyperlink to internal page number

Tags: php, mpdf

Is it possible to create a hyperlink to specific page without using the `name` attribute? I'm trying to create a link without anchors. Something like:

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf($mpdfOptions);
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<a href="#page=2">Go To Page 2</a>');
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->WriteHTML("Content for page 2");    
$mpdf->Output();
```